# TSQL relative week numbering

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Scenario:**
I have a table with a field WeekNr, it's the week's number. This week it's 42, last week it was 41, etc, etc.

**Challenge:**
I have to "translate" this numbering to relative numbering, the logic is the following:

If this week is week 42, then my view has to return 0. For week 41, it's -1, week 40 will be -2 and so on, until -12 weeks. The biggest WeekNr is the week 0 for sure.

**Question:**
How would you solve this in a single query?

Comment: So, `WeekNr - DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE())`?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear. What is the zero-point?

Comment: The zero-point is the biggest week number in the table. It's not based on GETDATE().

Comment: @KatalinPap `If this week is week 42`, doesn't that means is based on `GETDATE()`?

Comment: That's correct. This is week 42, but now the max(weeknr) I have in the table is 40. And in this case, 40 has to be Week 0. This information is given in the dashboard to the user, that week 0 is week 40, it's the last feed we received from business.

Comment: @KatalinPap So then use `WeekNr - MAX(WeekNr) OVER()`

Comment: Perfect :D I came to the conclusion after I used the magic word ("max"). A minor facepalm to me! Thank you guys, you are awesome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
WeekNr - MAX(WeekNr)
```

Comment: Not literally, though. It would have to be either `WeekNr - MAX(WeekNr) OVER ()` or something like `WeekNr - (SELECT MAX(WeekNr) FROM dbo.YourTable)`. Alternatively you could `CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(WeekNr) FROM dbo.YourTable) AS x (MaxWeekNr)` and then you'd be able to do `WeekNr - x.MaxWeekNr` in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Indeed, I ended up using the CROSS JOIN! thanks, Andriy!